# How to set default path for save captured video using HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, video

I'm trying to do eye blink detection using MediaRecorderAPI with HTML and Java-script and i have captured video and download it with my normal downloaded path which is my default browser path from that i have pass my video and detecting eye blink. But my problem is i want to create a directory in my project for downloading captured videos. Please can anyone help me... Thanks in advance :)

here is my html index.html and main.js:

```js
'use strict';

/* globals MediaRecorder */

// Spec is at http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/tip/media-stream-capture/RecordingProposal.html

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;


if (getBrowser() == "Chrome") {
  var constraints = {
    "audio": true,
    "video": {
      "mandatory": {
        "minWidth": 640,
        "maxWidth": 640,
        "minHeight": 480,
        "maxHeight": 480
      },
      "optional": []
    }
  }; //Chrome did not support the new constraints spec until 59 for video and 60 for audio
} else if (getBrowser() == "Firefox") {
  var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
      width: {
        min: 640,
        ideal: 640,
        max: 640
      },
      height: {
        min: 480,
        ideal: 480,
        max: 480
      }
    }
  }; //Firefox
}

var recBtn = document.querySelector('button#rec');
var pauseResBtn = document.querySelector('button#pauseRes');
var stopBtn = document.querySelector('button#stop');

var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
var dataElement = document.querySelector('#data');
var downloadLink = document.querySelector('a#downloadLink');

videoElement.controls = false;

function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

/*
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
var sourceBuffer;
*/

var mediaRecorder;
var chunks = [];
var count = 0;

function startRecording(stream) {
  log('Start recording...');
  if (typeof MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported == 'function') {
    /*
     MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported is a function announced in https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder and later introduced in the MediaRecorder API spec http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/
    */
    if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')) {
      var options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'
      };
    } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=h264')) {
      var options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'
      };
    } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp8')) {
      var options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'
      };
    }
    log('Using ' + options.mimeType);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
  } else {
    log('isTypeSupported is not supported, using default codecs for browser');
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  }

  pauseResBtn.textContent = "Pause";

  mediaRecorder.start(10);

  var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  videoElement.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
  videoElement.play();

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    //log('Data available...');
    //console.log(e.data);
    //console.log(e.data.type);
    //console.log(e);
    chunks.push(e.data);
  };

  mediaRecorder.onerror = function(e) {
    log('Error: ' + e);
    console.log('Error: ', e);
  };


  mediaRecorder.onstart = function() {
    log('Started & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
  };

  mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var mins = dt.getMinutes();
    // var dot =dot.getDot();
    var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
    log('Stopped  & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);

    var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
      type: "video/mp4"
    });
    chunks = [];
    // xhr.open("GET", "/favicon.png");
    var videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    downloadLink.href = videoURL;
    videoElement.src = videoURL;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = 'Download video file';

    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000));
    // var location =("D:/mine project/Media-Recorder-API-Demo-master/video" + rand + postfix+ ".mp4");
    var name = ("video" + "_" + rand + "_" + postfix + ".mp4");
    // var name  = ("D:/mine project/Media-Recorder-API-Demo-master"+"video_"+rand+".mp4") ;
    downloadLink.setAttribute("download", name);
    downloadLink.setAttribute("name", name);
  };

  mediaRecorder.onpause = function() {
    log('Paused & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
  }

  mediaRecorder.onresume = function() {
    log('Resumed  & state = ' + mediaRecorder.state);
  }

  mediaRecorder.onwarning = function(e) {
    log('Warning: ' + e);
  };
}

//function handleSourceOpen(event) {
//  console.log('MediaSource opened');
//  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp9"');
//  console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer);
//}

function onBtnRecordClicked() {
  if (typeof MediaRecorder === 'undefined' || !navigator.getUserMedia) {
    alert('MediaRecorder not supported on your browser, use Firefox 30 or Chrome 49 instead.');
  } else {
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, startRecording, errorCallback);
    recBtn.disabled = true;
    pauseResBtn.disabled = false;
    stopBtn.disabled = false;
  }
}

function onBtnStopClicked() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  videoElement.controls = true;

  recBtn.disabled = false;
  pauseResBtn.disabled = true;
  stopBtn.disabled = true;
}

function onPauseResumeClicked() {
  if (pauseResBtn.textContent === "Pause") {
    console.log("pause");
    pauseResBtn.textContent = "Resume";
    mediaRecorder.pause();
    stopBtn.disabled = true;
  } else {
    console.log("resume");
    pauseResBtn.textContent = "Pause";
    mediaRecorder.resume();
    stopBtn.disabled = false;
  }
  recBtn.disabled = true;
  pauseResBtn.disabled = false;
}


function log(message) {
  dataElement.innerHTML = dataElement.innerHTML + '<br>' + message;
}



//browser ID
function getBrowser() {
  var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
  var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
  var browserName = navigator.appName;
  var fullVersion = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
  var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
  var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

  // In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
  if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Opera")) != -1) {
    browserName = "Opera";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
    if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Version")) != -1)
      fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
  }
  // In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("MSIE")) != -1) {
    browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
  }
  // In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome"
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Chrome")) != -1) {
    browserName = "Chrome";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
  }
  // In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version"
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Safari")) != -1) {
    browserName = "Safari";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
    if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Version")) != -1)
      fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
  }
  // In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox"
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Firefox")) != -1) {
    browserName = "Firefox";
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
  }
  // In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent
  else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) <
    (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
    browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
    fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
    if (browserName.toLowerCase() == browserName.toUpperCase()) {
      browserName = navigator.appName;
    }
  }
  // trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
  if ((ix = fullVersion.indexOf(";")) != -1)
    fullVersion = fullVersion.substring(0, ix);
  if ((ix = fullVersion.indexOf(" ")) != -1)
    fullVersion = fullVersion.substring(0, ix);

  majorVersion = parseInt('' + fullVersion, 10);
  if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
    fullVersion = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
  }


  return browserName;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta id="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#fff">
  <base target="_blank">
  <title>Media Recorder API Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
  <style>
    a#downloadLink {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 0 1em 0;
      min-height: 1.2em;
    }
    
    p#data {
      min-height: 6em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <h1>Media Recorder API Demo </h1>
      <video controls autoplay></video><br>
      <button id="rec" onclick="onBtnRecordClicked()">Record</button>
      <button id="pauseRes" onclick="onPauseResumeClicked()" disabled>Pause</button>
      <button id="stop" onclick="onBtnStopClicked()" disabled>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <a id="downloadLink" name="mediarecorder.mp4" download=""></a>
    <p id="data"></p>
    <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So u want assistance in creating directory (on the go) or with setting default path?

Comment: sir programmatically i want set directory to store captured values.

Comment: if triggering download is issue, I can help; But setting download directory by overriding default download directory is (from what I researched) is a security issue.. What are ur plans?

Comment: sir my another option is i return my video as blob URL using python but now  i want to show the blob URL as video/mp4.

Comment: First pls dont sir me; Secondly see if this helps;

here 'vid' is blob file; ; 

function display(vid){

    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(vid);

}

Comment: please can u replace it in my above js code.

Comment: i cant edit it; I will paste as answer; if it doesnt work, i will remove it; OK?

Comment: In my js code blob value is in videoURL and i want to show the captured blob below the video recorder..can u replace it. :)

Comment: sure sir.. u just paste i will try..

Comment: hate to be the bringer of bad news; but my logic is already there in your code; if it is still not working. I dont know why.

Comment: ok :) thanks for your tips and help